# Verify input text element is not empty in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, verify

How can I verify that an input element has any text in it. It is loaded with random text so I can't verify a specific value, but there must be some text in it.
I'm using Selenium IDE

Answer (score 5):

In Selenium IDE you can use the `verifyEval` command and a bit of JavaScript to verify that a field is populated, or not.

```
Command: verifyEval
Target:  this.page().findElement("//input[@id='email']").value != ''
Value:   true
```

In this case, I'm testing that the `<input type="email" id="email" value='address@domain.com">` is not an empty field on my HTML page.

When this command is run, the JavaScript code in the target is evaluated.  Here it is testing the current value of the email field against an empty string.  If they don't match (e.g. the field isn't empty) then it `true` is returned.  This return value is then compared to the expected `Value` which is also true and so the test passes.

Comment: verifyEval doesn't seem to exist in the Chrome or Firefox versions of Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 3):

I just use

```
verifyNotValue|//input[@id='email']|
```

the 3rd param is empty

Comment: verifyNotValue doesn't seem to exist in the Chrome or Firefox versions of Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a cinch if you use Selenium-RC with any programming language. However, given that you are using the IDE, I would recommend adding [this](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html) user extension. This will give you some looping constructs. You can use  `storeText`  and then take a decision based on the value of the variable in which the retrieved text is stored. The [Stored Vars](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/stored-variables-viewer-seleni/) is another useful IDE firefox extension for analyzing the contents of the `storeText` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> driver.find_element_by_id("email").get_attribute("value") != ''

Comment: The question is about the IDE version, not the web driver, so this answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It was part of a sign up form assertion. 
The firstName field was provided with data. Then i used the following code to verify whether the field was filled up with data.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#FirstName")).getText()==""){
        System.out.println("field didn't fillup with data");
    } 
else {
        System.out.println("field filled up with data");
    }
```

Comment: The question is about the IDE version, not the web driver, so this answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is 12 years later, but I was having this same issue and I couldn't find the answer, so I did it in a slightly more brute force way since it doesn't seem that there is a single command with an elegant solution. This is for Selenium IDE 4.0.1-alpha.78

This is a 4 command solution, but it works.

Format is (Command ---> Target ---> Value)

```
 1. execute script ---> return $('selector').get(0).value != '' ---> valExists
 2. if ---> !${valExists}
 3.   assert ---> your error message that will stop test execution
 4. end
```

Line 1 returns the result of the logical comparison into the variable ${valExists} so that holds boolean true or false after execution.

Line 2 just checks the boolean value. Since you can't execute a script in an "if" statement, it has to be executed in the line before.

I'm sure this would work with anything that you need a value but you don't care what that value is. In my script, I also have an echo after the execute script to just log the result.

Hopefully this can help people from the future.

Edited for clarity.